# Error when interacting from Hive to Druid

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, druid

I'm trying to create a Druid datasource from Hive and I'm using table Hive for it.

First, I created a database Hive : `database_hive` then, I created a table in this database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE database_hive.hive_table (
    timemachine int,
    userId String,
    lang String,
    location String,
    name String,
    network String,
    posted String,
    sentiment String,
    text String,
);
```

In a second time, i'm trying to use `hive_table` for create a new datasource on Druid.

```sql
SET hive.druid.broker.address.default = 10.1.123.30:8082; --fake ip for example
SET hive.druid.metadata.username = druid;
SET hive.druid.metadata.password = druidpassword;
SET hive.druid.metadata.db.type = derby;
SET hive.druid.metadata.uri = jdbc:mysql://10.1.123.30:3306/druid?createDatabaseIfNoExist=true;

CREATE TABLE druid_table
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.druid.DruidStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "druid.segment.granularity" = "MONTH",
    "druid.query.granularity" = "DAY")
    AS
    SELECT
    cast(timemachine as timestamp) as `__time`,   
    cast(userId as string) userId,
    cast(lang as string) lang,
    cast(location as string) location,
    cast(name as string) name,
    cast(network as string) network,
    cast(posted as string) posted,
    cast(sentiment as string) sentiment,
    cast(text as string) text
    FROM hive_table
;
```

This query return me an error :

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToObtainConnectionException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://10.1.123.30:3306/druid?createDatabaseIfNoExist=true' (state=08S01,code=1)
```

In my Hive repository, i've `mysql-connector-java.jar` so I don't understand what's the problem. I've tried some proposals that I read on other topics but I didn't find solution.
Someone has suggestions?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your Druid metadata DB configuration. 
The Hive needs access to the relational database that Druid uses to store all the metadata. It can be set to `derby` on Druid side, but Derby is like SQLite, so it can't be accessed by Hive. Thus, Hive doesn't allow `derby` as a valid argument to `hive.druid.metadata.db.type` property. The only allowed are `mysql` and `postgresql`.

So to fix this issue you need:

- Make sure that your Druid cluster uses either MySQL or PSQL for metadata storage
- Set `hive.druid.metadata.db.type` to the correct db type
- Set `hive.druid.metadata.uri` to correct DB url

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. That help me a lot. Now, i can request my Druid with Postgre connector. My second request doesn't work but it's not a problem because i can make that more simply. I follow this documentation for end my job : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Druid+Integration